# Optimizing performance of Python code for large datasets

Tags: python, dataset

I have a Python script that processes large datasets, and I'm looking for ways to optimize its performance. The code currently takes a significant amount of time to run, and I'm wondering if there are any strategies or best practices I can follow to improve its efficiency.

```
# Load large dataset into memory
data = load_large_dataset()

# Process each data point
results = []
for item in data:
    # Perform complex calculations
    result = perform_calculations(item)

    # Store result
    results.append(result)

# Further processing on results
final_output = process_results(results)

# Output final result
print(final_output)
```

I would appreciate any suggestions or recommendations on how to optimize this code. Are there any specific Python libraries or techniques I should consider? How can I parallelize the calculations to take advantage of multiple CPU cores? Any guidance on improving memory usage or reducing unnecessary computations would be extremely helpful.

I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: It depends on what's taking a long time. For example, if *perform_calculations()* is CPU intensive you should consider multiprocessing. If it's I/O bound then multithreading might be a good solution